# Working with delegates Action<string>

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, anonymous-function, linq-to-twitter

So I am trying to authenticate some user on twitter api using LinqToTwitter.

```
public class PinAuthorizer : AuthorizerBase, IAuthorizer
{
        public PinAuthorizer();
        public PinAuthorizer(bool forceLogin);
        public PinAuthorizer(bool forceLogin, AuthAccessType accessType);
        public PinAuthorizer(bool forceLogin, AuthAccessType accessType, string preFillScreenName);

        public Func<string> GetPin { get; set; }
        public Action<string> GoToTwitterAuthorization { get; set; }
        public Task CompleteAuthorizeAsync(string pin);
}
```

The problem is I dont know how to work with this delegate. I'm trying:

```
 Authorizer = new PinAuthorizer {
                            CredentialStore = new InMemoryCredentialStore {
                                    ConsumerKey = ConsumerKey,
                                    ConsumerSecret = ConsumerSecret,
                                    ScreenName = Name
                            }
                    };
 WebBrowserControl.Navigate(Authorizer.GoToTwitterAuthorization);
```

I get null reference exception.

**UPDATE**: I'am not trying to understand why the null reference happens. **I'm trying to understand how can I correctly use the delegate so I can go to the authorization url with my WebBrowser control**. **Please read the question before marking it as duplicate.**